# Why won't this magnetic field plot?

Tags: plotting, function-construction, vector-calculus

I have been having some longstanding trouble in getting a 2D vector plot of a magnetic field to show up. For context, I am working with Lienard-Wiechert potentials and as such trying to plot the curl of a vector potential.

These are the constants that get used:

```
q = 1; (*elementary charge*)
c = 1;(*speed of light*)
\[CurlyEpsilon] = 1;(*vacuum permittivity of free space*)
\[Mu] = 1;(*vacuum permeability of free space*)
u = 0.1*c;
```

These are the variables and functions that end up in the vector potential equation:

```
xs[t_] := (u*Cos[30 Degree]*t) ;(*x-pos of source*)
ys[t_] := (u*Sin[30 Degree]*t) ;(*y-pos of source*)
rs[t_] := {xs[t], ys[t]};(*location of the source*)
v[t_] = D[rs[t], t];(*velocity of source*)

r = {x, y};(*location of the field point*)

tr[r_, t_] := t - Norm[r - rs[t]]/c (*the retarded time as a function of the separation distance
 and time elapsed*)
```

And this is the code for the Lienard-Wiechert vector potential:

```
LWV[r_, t_] := (\[Mu]/4*Pi) (q*c*v[tr[r, t]]/
      (Norm[r - rs[t]]*c -
        Dot[r - rs[t], v[tr[r, t]]]));(*equation for the Lienard-Wiechert vector potential*)
```

I have been trying to get it to plot by doing this:

```
LWMField[r_, t_] :=  Curl[LWV[r, t] /. Abs@x_^2 :> x^2, {x,  y}](*LW magnetic field equation *)
VectorPlot[Evaluate@LWMField[r, 0], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}] (*vector plot of the LW magnetic field*)
```

But all I get back from that is a sad empty box and Mathematica telling me "Part is not a Graphics primitive or directive." I looked up the error but did not get any insight on what exactly it means nor where the problem is. Does anybody have any thoughts or ideas of where I messed up here?  Here is a picture of exactly the error I am getting:

[image: Emtpy plot and error message from trying to vector plot LWMField]

Thanks for any help you all can provide!

Comment: Please check `LWMField[r, 0]` ,here it is only a scalar function,not a vector function.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on the previous comment, you appear to be mixing Cartesian and polar coordinates in your equations, but you don't convert back and forth correctly. I.e. you take the curl of LWV[r,t] wrt x,y, You probably want to use r->Sqrt[x^2+y^2] here before computing the curl. Your vector field plot has LWMField depending on r, theta, but you plot using x,y. You need to fix these inconsistencies.

Comment: @JDRobin Actually magnetic field in a case of LW is 3D field. Add coordinate `zs[t_]:=0` to `rs` and `z` to `r`.  Use `VectorPlot3D` to visualize field.

Comment: Also, please note, that retarded time should be defined in an implicit form as solution of equation `tr== t - Norm[r - rs[tr]]/c`.

Comment: @jdp Thank you so much for elaborating on that further. The whole time I've been doing this I couldn't shake the feeling that I was flip-flopping coordinate systems, especially when I started taking curls. Since the LWMField is dependent on r and theta, I took Alex's advice and added in the missing z component to both position vectors.

Comment: @AlexTrounev You're a life saver! That fix makes a lot of sense since I don't ever really recall dealing with magnetic fields in a 2D space or seeing them plotted in such. I made the change and the magnetic field plots just fine. Could you perhaps elaborate further on why in the equation for tr, I should change rs[t] to rs[tr]? Is it because the retarded time is measured from where the charge was when it first emitted the light received by the observer? If so, isn't that recursive?

Comment: Yes this is a recursive and difficult problem to compute retarded time as a function of coordinate and time. Fortunately, in a linear case as you consider above it is not so difficult.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I've been trying to look up dealing with recursive formulas in Mathematica and have not had much success. All I found was something on "RSolve" but I do not get how to use it. I was hoping if I could employ your help? Should I make a new post about the recursion so we can discuss it?

Comment: Yes, it could be better to start a new post about retarded time calculation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I went on ahead and did just that. I would appreciate your input if you are able, you've been a phenomenal help.